# When do we use the verb third form?

Tags: verbs

> I had left the train before my brother spoken.
>   I had left the train before my brother spoke.
>   I had left the train before my brother speak.

What is difference, can anyone explain?

Comment: You might find [**this**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tags/verb-forms/info) helpful.

Comment: Or this: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/81998/when-do-we-add-ed-at-the-end-of-a-verb

Comment: You should use the proper term: third base form or past participle. Otherwise you can't find information about this verb form on the internet.

Answer (score 3):

```
 I had left the train before my brother spoke.
```

not `spoken`

```
 I had left the train before my brother spoken.
```

This is incorrect because it lacks an auxiliary verb.. Without the auxiliary verb, spoken takes on the form of an adjective.

> The words are spoken
>
> The spoken words were fantastic

To make your incorrect sentence correct, you simply need to add the verb `to have`

> I had left the train before my brother had spoken.

In  this example, we are using the past perfect tense of `to have`

> My brother had spoken
>
> [........] had eaten
>
> [........] had fallen
>
> [........] had jumped
>
> [........] had unexpectedly lain an egg, like a chicken.

Your last sentence is also incorrect

```
 I had left the train before my brother speak.
```

This makes no sense at all.

It needs to be in the past tense.

> my brother speak[s]
>
> my brother **spoke**

and it would then be correct.