# When do we add 'ed' at the end of a verb?

Tags: past-tense, subject-verb-agreement

I read a sentence from a forum:

> Because the Community College has limited research opportunities, ...

I notice that there is 'ed' with **limit**. I don't think it follows the rule: have/has + past tense verb.

Comment: The rule for the perfect construction is *HAVE* + **past participle**, not 'past tense'. With regular verbs the past participle and past-tense forms are identical, but with irregular verbs they often differ -- for instance *were - been*, *swam - swum*, *threw - thrown*.

Comment: Can you please say why you don't think it follows the rule? Because "-ed" endings *are* for past tense (and, as @StoneyB says, past participles).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Has limited* is not a perfect here (*HAVE* + Past Participle) but an accidental collocation: *has* is the lexical verb rather than the auxiliary, and the participle acts as an ordinary adjective.

This could be paraphrased

> Because the Community College provides few research opportunities ...

Comment: It's not clear to me without context whether *limited* is a verb or an adjective here.

Answer (score 2):

Regular verbs have the basic forms as in open/opened/opened. The second basic form is only used for past tense as in I opened the window.

The third base form, the past participle, is used for the perfect tenses:
I have opened, I had opened, I will have opened, I would have opened.

It is also used in all passive forms of the verb.

The past participle has a third use, it can be used as adjective as in:
the opened window.

In "limited research" limited is used as an adjective.

Perhaps this will help:

```
The tense system in English is relatively simple:
```

Forms I

Pr I have1 (he has, not: he haves) - have1 is Present Tense, no infinitive

Pt I had2 -- had2 is the second "stem form" and Past Tense

F1 I will1 have0 - have0 is an infinitive

C1 I would2* have0 - have0 is an infinitive, would2* is Past subjunctive

Forms II

Pf I have1 had3 --- had3 is the third stem form

PP I had2 had3

F2 I will1 have0 had3 --- have had is infinitive perfect, have0 inf. + had3

C2 I would2* have0 had3

The progressive tenses

are no conjugation at all. They are a pseudo-conjugation. 
They are nothing but the forms of to be + participle/gerund (whatever you like to call it).
English grammars tend to mix the normal tenses with the progressive forms and get a horrible conjugation table.

This is taken from: http://forum.thefreedictionary.com/postst52180_Who-knows-which-tenses-of-English-are-not-used-or-used-merely-.aspx
Have a look there. The optical arrangement is better there.

The best conjugation tables are in verbix.com. They have a logical arrangement
http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/English/be.html  Unfortunately they have forgotten the forms of the infinitives and participles/gerunds and also the passive voice.